# replacement of pattern in vim editor

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, awk, sed, vim

I have a file with following pattern

```
property1:  value1
property2:  value2
property3:  value3
property4:  value4
property5:  value5
```

Value could be ipv4/ipv6 ip address, number, string etc.

How can this be modified to something like using available text editor tools:

```
property1  "value1";
property2  "value2";
property3  "value3";
property4  "value4";
property5  "value5";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to record a macro.

1. Place a cursor on first line, first column
2. Make sure you are in "normal" mode.
3. Start recording a macro into "q" register by typing "qq"
4. `f:xwi"<Esc>$a";<Esc>0j`
5. Stop recording by typing `q`
6. Transform next line by typing `@q`
7. Repeat macro by typing `@@`

You will see your file transforming.

Detailed explanation of step 4:

- `f<char>` moves the cursor to next occurence of . That's how we get from the first column of the line to the index of `:`.
- `x` delete char under cursor.
- `w` moves us to next word, essentialy we are jumping over the whitespace
- `i` enters insert mode, so we can type new characters. We are inserting `"` and exiting insert mode by pressing Esc.
- `$` gets us to the end of the line.
- `a` again enters insert mode, but cursor is placed after current position (essentialy `$a` means append to end of the line)
- We insert last chars `";` and we again exit insert mode with Esc.
- `0` moves to the beginning of the line, and `j` moves one line down. This last step is so the macro can be repeated without much thinking.

Comment: But we have to execute macro on all lines ? can we execute macro 10 times in a short ?

Comment: Yes, you just type `10@q`, which means "execute macro from q register 10 times"

Answer (score 1):

That's a job for sed, not vim. Using any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/:\([[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1"\2";/' file
property1  "value1";
property2  "value2";
property3  "value3";
property4  "value4";
property5  "value5";
```